# Wrong number of days Excel

Tags: excel, date, datediff, date-difference

I am trying to calculate the difference between days but receiving the wrong number of total days for that year. For the dates 2016-01-01 and 2016-12-31 I receive 365 days but not 366. I used the following function where I receive the same output:

```
=DAYS("2016-12-31","2016-1-1")
=DATEDIF("2016-1-1","2016-12-31","d")
="2016-12-31"-"2016-1-1"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Soemhow the leap year's are not properly accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the output from the `DATEDIF` function.  Consider the following function call:

```
=DATEDIF("2016-12-30", "2016-12-31", "d")
```

This returns 1, which is the number of days between the two dates.  Similarly, the following call returns 365:

```
=DATEDIF("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31", "d")
```

A value of 365 means that there are 365 days between the *first* day of the year (day #1, January 1), and the 366 day of the year (day #366, December 31).

As a sanity check, run the following:

```
=DATEDIF("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31", "d")
```

This returns 364 days, because 2015 was not a leap year and had no February 29 in its calendar.

Note that the end date must always be greater than the start date, otherwise you will get the `#NUM!` error.  The call you made in your question will not even work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is the proper way the get the proper days and account for leap years?

Comment: @MCM I guess my answer was not clear or maybe you did not read it.  `DATEDIF` _does_ return the correct number of days, regardless of leap year.  You only need to add one to get the total number of days.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was not clear for me adding a 1. But is it all the time adding a one irrespectivly which date I am including.

Comment: @MCM Yes, because this is the nature of a date difference.

Comment: But using the logic you suggest for this dates 2016-06-01 and 2016-09-01 would give me 93 days instead of 92

Comment: `DATEDIF("2016-06-01", "2016-09-01", "d")` gives 92 as the result, which makes sense because we are subtracting day 93 minus day 1.

Comment: but somehow this is somehow to manual adding and subrtracting one day. I am looking for a universal function which knows already that it is a leap day or not and gives me the proper number of days irrespectively which dates I am providing

Comment: I don't understand what is not clear here.  If I give you the sequence `1,2,3,4,5`, and I ask for the _difference_ between 1 and 5, the answer is 4.  But there are _five_, not four, numbers in the sequence.

Comment: It is clear concerning the datedif function. I wanted more method which already accounts directly for leap days and not looking which year has one and then add something or not and which is dependent on the dates I include. Hope it is clearer?

Comment: @MCM The `Datedif` works fine and you don't have to selectively add 1 to it. You need to have +1 appended to all Datedif formulas or alternatively you startdate should be 'startdate - 1' to include that date itself otherwise it counts after that date

Comment: @PankajR, thanks a lot. but somehow i am receving also with the startdate + 1 a number of days, e.g. 2016-06-01 and 2016-09-01 I receive 93 days but it should be 92.

Comment: Can you clarify how are thinking about start or end date - whether those should be excluded or included. in the present case, normally the calc goes like this: June+July+Aug+1 day of Sep = 30+31+31+1 = 93. So 93 is correct answer with +1 appended

Comment: @all, I think i have it now.